# Using the _Generic macro in C11 fails

Tags: c, macros, overriding, c11

I tried to overload a function with the C11 `_Generic` macro like this:

```
int isPrim_int   (int num);  
int isPrim_lint  (long int num);  
int isPrim_llint (long long int num);

#define isPrim(_1, ...) _Generic((_1),                              \
                          int:              isPrim_int,             \
                          long int:         isPrim_lint,            \
                          long long int:    isPrim_llint)
```

But for some reason using `isPrim()` returns always 1, when using the specific three functions `isPrim_int`, `isPrim_lint` and `isPrim_llint` it works as intended. Any clues whats wrong with my use of the macro?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you call it? How come the calling code is not shown?

Comment: I tested the function implemention of the three functions itself, so I assumed the error is with the macro implementation and the actual functions irrelavant for the question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You "forgot" to post the calling code, but my crystal ball is telling me that most likely you are "selecting" a function, but never actually calling it. Your current `_Generic` simply evaluates to a function pointer, which is later interpreted as "true" in boolean context.

Apply the `()` operator to the result of your `_Generic` expression to actually *call* the function. E.g.

```
#define isPrim(_1, ...) _Generic((_1),                              \
                          int:              isPrim_int,             \
                          long int:         isPrim_lint,            \
                          long long int:    isPrim_llint)(_1)
```

Your original version will also work, but you'd have to use it as follows

```
int a = 42;
if (isPrim(a)(a))
   ...
```

which is probably not how you intended it to be used.